# Queries from large csv files using dask are very slow

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dask

I want to query only the rows for a specific user ID from a large csv file with 100 million rows that has multiple columns containing the user ID.
There are about 400,000 user IDs in this file.

Since the csv file is too large to get in memory, I wrote the program using dask as below.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
ddf = dd.read_csv('large.csv')
df = ddf[ddf['user_id'] == 'fja8947']
df = df.compute()
```

However, the execution time of the program below that executes the query takes about 4 minutes, which is very slow.

How can I improve the program or change the format of the file so that it can be queried faster?

Comment: Are you repeatedly asking for different User ID's or are you just going to your data source once and then working with 1 User ID?  If you are only getting new ID occasionally, you could modify your read-in to only read rows with the user ID of interest and hold stuff in a dictionary or such rather than use dask to bring "everything" in and then filter.  Basically, filter when you read.

Comment: Your other option is to bite the bullet and teach yourself a little about data bases, which would be a better setup for data of that length and quickly query-able if indexed correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
I want to access all user IDs and process those rows.
I want to do a lot of queries for all user IDs instead of occasionally fetching for one user ID.